# How to read sei by command line of ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

How to read sei by command line of ffmpeg.
e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -c:v copy -bsf:v filter1[=opt1=str1:opt2=str2][,filter2] OUTPUT
```

I know bsf can modify the sei, but it can't read sei.

If the command line can't solve it, plase give me some demo by api of ffmpeg.

For example.

I insert a h264_metadata to file.

```
ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_metadata=sei_user_data='086f3693-b7b3-4f2c-9653-21492feee5b8+hello' file_with_h264_metadata.mp4
```

and then I push it to rtmp

```
ffmpeg -re -i ./file_with_h264_metadata.mp4 -vcodec h264 -f flv  rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/h264_metadata
```

How can I extact the h264_metadata with ffmpeg command line?

I have try this, but it does not work

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/h264_metadata -c:v copy -bsf:v h264_metadata -f null -
```

Comment: SEI is Supplemental Enhancement Information, exists in ffmpeg's code stream.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't clear what you mean by "read", but if you simply want to print the contents of the SEI NALs, [trace_headers](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#trace_005fheaders) bitstream filter may be useful. It's very noisy, so you would need to filter the output.

Example: `ffmpeg -i <inputfile> -c:v copy -bsf:v trace_headers -f null -`

A random file I just tried includes the following in the output:

```
[AVBSFContext @ 0x7fffbfeb6040] Supplemental Enhancement Information
[AVBSFContext @ 0x7fffbfeb6040] 0           forbidden_zero_bit                                          0 = 0
[AVBSFContext @ 0x7fffbfeb6040] 1           nal_ref_idc                                                00 = 0
[AVBSFContext @ 0x7fffbfeb6040] 3           nal_unit_type                                           00110 = 6
[AVBSFContext @ 0x7fffbfeb6040] 8           last_payload_type_byte                               00000100 = 4
[AVBSFContext @ 0x7fffbfeb6040] 16          last_payload_size_byte                               00010001 = 17
[AVBSFContext @ 0x7fffbfeb6040] User Data Registered ITU-T T.35
[AVBSFContext @ 0x7fffbfeb6040] 24          itu_t_t35_country_code                               10110101 = 181
[AVBSFContext @ 0x7fffbfeb6040] 32          itu_t_t35_payload_byte[1]                            00000000 = 0
[AVBSFContext @ 0x7fffbfeb6040] 40          itu_t_t35_payload_byte[2]                            00110001 = 49
[AVBSFContext @ 0x7fffbfeb6040] 48          itu_t_t35_payload_byte[3]                            01000111 = 71
[AVBSFContext @ 0x7fffbfeb6040] 56          itu_t_t35_payload_byte[4]                            01000001 = 65
[AVBSFContext @ 0x7fffbfeb6040] 64          itu_t_t35_payload_byte[5]                            00111001 = 57
[AVBSFContext @ 0x7fffbfeb6040] 72          itu_t_t35_payload_byte[6]                            00110100 = 52
[AVBSFContext @ 0x7fffbfeb6040] 80          itu_t_t35_payload_byte[7]                            00000011 = 3
[AVBSFContext @ 0x7fffbfeb6040] 88          itu_t_t35_payload_byte[8]                            11000010 = 194
[AVBSFContext @ 0x7fffbfeb6040] 96          itu_t_t35_payload_byte[9]                            11111111 = 255
[AVBSFContext @ 0x7fffbfeb6040] 104         itu_t_t35_payload_byte[10]                           11111100 = 252
[AVBSFContext @ 0x7fffbfeb6040] 112         itu_t_t35_payload_byte[11]                           10010111 = 151
[AVBSFContext @ 0x7fffbfeb6040] 120         itu_t_t35_payload_byte[12]                           00100011 = 35
[AVBSFContext @ 0x7fffbfeb6040] 128         itu_t_t35_payload_byte[13]                           11111101 = 253
[AVBSFContext @ 0x7fffbfeb6040] 136         itu_t_t35_payload_byte[14]                           10000000 = 128
[AVBSFContext @ 0x7fffbfeb6040] 144         itu_t_t35_payload_byte[15]                           10000000 = 128
[AVBSFContext @ 0x7fffbfeb6040] 152         itu_t_t35_payload_byte[16]                           11111111 = 255
```

Comment: Hi, I supply an example. Could you give me some advice again?